# PowerBi Desktop: Distinct Measure Missing values

Tags: count, powerbi, distinct, measure

I have a problem with a measure / calculation producing inconsistent data for which I would need help.

I'm importing data from Active Directoy which is working fine. I use the AccountLockoutState to determine if a computer is active or not. Besides that I have a conditional column to aggregate OS in a simplified version - all working fine.

I the have 3 different measures to count the distinct number of devices with the followin attributes:

1. All Active clients:

```
AD Total = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('AD Data'[computer.cn]),
    FILTER(
        'AD Data',
        'AD Data'[userAccountControl]= VALUE("4096") 
            || 'AD Data'[userAccountControl] = Value("4128") 
            || 'AD Data'[userAccountControl] = Value("69632")
    )
)
```

2. All Active Clients with OS Win7 or Win 10

```
AD In Scope = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('AD Data'[computer.cn]),
    FILTER(
        'AD Data',
        'AD Data'[OS] = "Win 7" 
        || 'AD Data'[OS] = "Win 10"
    ),
    FILTER(
        'AD Data',
        'AD Data'[userAccountControl]= VALUE("4096") 
        || 'AD Data'[userAccountControl] = Value("4128") 
        || 'AD Data'[userAccountControl] = Value("69632")
    )
)
```

3. All Clients not with Win 7 or Win 10

```
AD Out Scope = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('AD Data'[computer.cn]),
    FILTER(
        'AD Data','AD Data'[OS] <> "Win 7" 
        && 'AD Data'[OS] <> "Win 10"
    ),
    FILTER(
        'AD Data',
        'AD Data'[userAccountControl]= VALUE("4096") 
        || 'AD Data'[userAccountControl] = Value("4128") 
        || 'AD Data'[userAccountControl] = Value("69632")
    )
)
```

Normally I would expect that Measure 2 + Measure 3 = Measure 1

However in my case I have a difference of 4 Clients that are simply not showing up...

[Missing clients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB0eo.png)

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening or how to identify the "missing" clients?

Thx & BR
Daniel

Comment: Can you try with COUNT in place of DISTINCTCOUNT and check m2+m3 = m1 or not. You have also optimization scope in all your Measures.

Comment: Hi R_R, 

with COUNT I do get the same numbers despite that the total as well as all other numbers have risen now. I could I do the calculation w/o the risk of having dulicates in there (That's why I was using DISTINCT).
Also, which optimizations would you recommend if I may ask? Thx a lot for your reply!

Comment: First you need to point the issue for mismatch in total. Logically your measures are fine and it should be  m2+m3 = m1. Do you have any filtering in the page?

Comment: By that time I have no page filters in place nope and this is what really bothers me

Comment: Check is there any error in rows in your data or not? check data type of all columns once again and finally the relations between tables.

Comment: Table does not have relationship as it just an export. I have capitalized the hostname row, removed none printable characters and EOL breaks, and ensured that LogonType is a whole number and not sumarized. During Import I don't get any error message or hint about erro values. What else could I check?

Comment: You have done a lot already. bad luck the issue is still there. can you try to reproduce the same issue with a small amount of sample data? that case I can check the sample report if you keep the report on One or Google drive and give me the link.